# No output is coming in C program

Tags: c

I am new in C and trying to compile a C program to export in my oracle system , 
Created a C program and there is no error but while compiling no output is coming , 
pasting main() part of my program

```
int main()
{

    int returncode = 0;
    char inputEmail[257] = { "jim.leblanc@kjhasg.com" };
    char inputKey[65] = { "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234"};
    char outputEmail[257] = { "" };

    returncode = SHA2EmailChar(inputEmail, inputKey, outputEmail);

    return(returncode);

}
```

please suggest on this

Comment: what output are you expecting?

Comment: You never tell it to print anything (at least not in the code you provided)!

Answer (score 1):

To output something, you need to use `printf`, not `return`.

Comment: I tried everything printf , gets but its not working

Comment: @Abhimpi_05 Can you post the code of SHA2EmailChar as well?